# How to clean MacOS? (Ad keeps popping up)

Tags: macos, software

I installed some video player and might accidentally clicked to install something in my Mac. Then I deleted the player from the application folder. Now, after several hours, the system pops out a small window (alert window, with accept and reminder me later button on the right). Safari and AppStore also pop out with the PDFExpert app page shown. 
I am wondering is there any place to fix this issue. I didnot find anything special in my Notification center nor any special app installed in my Application folder. Is there anywhere else I need to check to fix it?

If no, I might need to us my timemachine to recover.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. Can you include a screenshot or two showing what it is that is popping up? And, what video player was it that you installed?

Comment: This is probably the nag for updating your computer. Open App Store and check the "Updates" tab to see if there's anything that's out-of-date.

Comment: @Monomeeth, I just saw that it is listed as "python" in my notification center. But I cannot find the app called "python" in my computer and I guess it probably a python script or something.

Answer (score 1):

I would run Malwarebytes Anti-Malware for the Mac and clean things up. It is free. Get it direct from Malwarebytes: https://www.malwarebytes.com/mac/